# How can I set the textfield as disabled and when typed, it will be enabled again?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I code this where the textfield's  original state will be disabled and then when typed in, it will be enabled. Then that textfield will be the only one be updated when submitted?

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                    id="input"
                    margin="dense"
                    type="text"
                    label="Name"
                    placeholder={user.displayName}
                    value={displayName}
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={(e) => setdisplayName(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    disabled
                    margin="dense"
                    type="text"
                    label="address"
                    value={address}
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                  />
            
                  <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
                </form>
```

Comment: You cannot type  on a disabled textfield. What do you want to achieve from this?

Comment: "The the textfield's original state will be disabled" What do you mean by this?

Comment: the problem with my code is that everytime i press submit,
displayname and the address both needs to be updated or else,
if I'll only edit the address, the name would be left and saved as an
empty string. So I thought to fix is to, disable the textfield, and whenever
the user will click it or starts typing, that textfield will be the only one that 
gets updated.

Comment: You can add some validation on submit

Answer (score 0):

Even though you disable one input, It still re-render everytime you typing (because you setState on change). You can use ref like this to prevent unnecessary render.

```
  const nameRef = useRef(null);
  const addressRef = useRef(null);
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(nameRef.current.value);
    console.log(addressRef.current.value);

  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id="input"
          margin="dense"
          type="text"
          label="Name"
          placeholder={user.displayName}
          fullWidth
          inputRef={nameRef}
        />
        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          type="text"
          label="address"
          fullWidth
          inputRef={addressRef}
        />

        <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
      </form>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation on `handleSubmit` because if a textfield is disabled, you need another action to make it enable and it's not ok for the user also.
You can try to add something like:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    if ((displayName === "" || displayName == null) && (address == "" || address === null) {
        //show error for user that both fields have to be completed
    } else {
        //do the form submit
    }
}
```